# Observables for number of functions

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

```
f1() {
 //API CALL
 console.log('f1');    
}

f2() {
 console.log('f2');
 for(i=0 ;i<=n; i++){
 }
}
```

I have two functions. I want these two to run one by other. Here I have  a for loop in the function 2. this for loop will use data from API call of function 1. So i want to use Observable to run these two one by one. I want to know a basic method how to create an observable and subscribe it so that these two dependent function will run one after another.

```
  apiParam: any = ['posts', 'albums', 'comments', 'photos', 'users'];

 getObs() {
const apiRoot = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
const urls = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.apiParam.length; i++) {
  urls.push(apiRoot + this.apiParam[i]);
  // const url = apiRoot + this.apiParam[i];
}
of(...urls).pipe(
  concatMap((url: string) => this.getHTTP.getData(url)))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.resultArray.push(result);
    console.log('this.resultArray', this.resultArray);
  });
}
```

This is the function whare i have used API call 
Now i want to use for loop and use this data this.resultArray.
like this

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.resultArray.length; index++) {
 console.log(this.apiParam[index]);
  this.finalObject = { [this.apiParam[index]]: this.resultArray[index] 
};
  this.finalArray.push(this.finalObject);
 }
 console.log('========this.finalArray============================');
 console.log(this.finalArray);
 console.log('====================================');
```

but whenever i am doing it the for loop is run first before getting the finalArray. 
Pleae help me out

Answer (score 0):

You could simply chain the first call to the second like so (inside your component):

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

first() {
  console.log('API called!');
}

second(data) {
  for (let item of data) {
    ...
  }
}

apiCall() {
  this.http.get(someURL).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.first();
      this.second(data);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: see my edits. 
this.first is running 5 times within. so if i ll write this.second immediately then this.second will not use the complete data. its simply releted to observables. i am not able to create one. so help me out in creating an observable